# Apollo Server Subscription Middleware to intercept request body to and request same request to different server

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I've a NodeJS Apollo Server with props

```
// Graphql server configuration.
  const graphqlServerConfig: ApolloServerExpressConfig = {
    schema: TEST_MODE ? mergedSchema : mergedSchemaWithPermissions,
    context: ({ req, res, connection }): GraphQLContext => {
      return {
        req,
        res,
        csctx,
      };
    },
    subscriptions: {
      path: '/subscriptions',
      keepAlive: 1000,
    },
    playground: {
      endpoint: '/core/graphql/',
      subscriptionEndpoint: '/core/graphql/subscriptions',
      settings: {
        'request.credentials': 'include',
      },
    },
  };
```

I need a middleware subscription that would subscribe to the remote server with the same request that I have gotten. Basically, in short, a UI will be requesting the subscription. On the basis of `connectionParams` I need to create a new websocket client on the server side and return whatever response we get from there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of intercepting a request and parsing it to figure out where to delegate it, you should consider [schema stitching](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/stitching/docs).

This example takes a graphql schema from a remote server and makes it available on your server while delegating the resolution of its operations (queries, mutations and subscriptions) to the remote server.

Make sure that remote server implements the same protocol to communicate with your server, in my case that is [GraphQL over WebSocket Protocol](https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md) as my remote is a Phoenix server with [absinthe_graphql_ws](https://hex.pm/packages/absinthe_graphql_ws).

```
import { Client, createClient } from "graphql-ws";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { WebSocket, WebSocketServer } from "ws";
import { useServer } from "graphql-ws/lib/use/ws";
import { GraphQLSchema, print } from "graphql";
import { AsyncExecutor, observableToAsyncIterable } from "@graphql-tools/utils";
import { schemaFromExecutor, wrapSchema } from "@graphql-tools/wrap";

import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { expressMiddleware } from "@apollo/server/express4";
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from "@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer";

import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";

const HTTP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:4001/api";
const WS_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = "ws://localhost:4001/api/graphql-ws";

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

const subscriptionClient = createClient({
  url: WS_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
  webSocketImpl: WebSocket,
});

const schema = await getRemoteSchema(subscriptionClient);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  server: httpServer,
  path: "/graphql",
});

const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
    {
      async serverWillStart() {
        return {
          async drainServer() {
            await serverCleanup.dispose();
          },
        };
      },
    },
  ],
});

await server.start();

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  cors<cors.CorsRequest>(),
  bodyParser.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server)
);

httpServer.listen(1338, () => {
  console.info('Server is running on http://localhost:1338/graphql')
});

async function getRemoteSchema(
  subscriptionClient: Client
): Promise<GraphQLSchema> {
  const httpExecutor: AsyncExecutor = async ({
    document,
    variables,
    operationName,
    extensions,
  }) => {
    const query = print(document);
    const fetchResult = await fetch(HTTP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables, operationName, extensions }),
    });
    return fetchResult.json();
  };

  const wsExecutor: AsyncExecutor = async ({
    document,
    variables,
    operationName,
    extensions,
  }) =>
    observableToAsyncIterable({
      subscribe: (observer) => ({
        unsubscribe: subscriptionClient.subscribe(
          {
            query: print(document),
            variables: variables as Record<string, any>,
            operationName,
            extensions,
          },
          {
            next: (data) => observer.next?.(data as unknown),
            error(err) {
              if (!observer.error) return;
              if (err instanceof Error) {
                observer.error(err);
              } else if (err instanceof CloseEvent) {
                observer.error(
                  new Error(`Socket closed with event ${err.code}`)
                );
              } else if (Array.isArray(err)) {
                // GraphQLError[]
                observer.error(
                  new Error(err.map(({ message }) => message).join(", "))
                );
              }
            },
            complete: () => observer.complete?.(),
          }
        ),
      }),
    });

  const executor: AsyncExecutor = async (executorRequest) => {
    if (executorRequest.operationType === "subscription") {
      return wsExecutor(executorRequest);
    }

    return httpExecutor(executorRequest);
  };

  const schema = wrapSchema({
    schema: await schemaFromExecutor(executor),
    executor,
  });

  return schema;
}
```

---

Using [graphql-yoga](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/yoga-server) instead of ApolloServer makes the code much slimmer:

```
// ... all imports except apollo & related, express
import { createYoga } from 'graphql-yoga'

// ...
const schema = await getRemoteSchema(subscriptionClient);
const yoga = createYoga({ schema: schema })
const server = createServer(yoga)

server.listen(1338, () => {
   console.info('Server is running on http://localhost:1338/graphql')
})
```

Hope it helps!

---

Exact dependency versions:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.7.1",
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^9.0.19",
    "@graphql-tools/wrap": "^9.4.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.5",
    "graphql-ws": "^5.12.1",
    "graphql-yoga": "^3.9.1",
    "ws": "^8.13.0"
  },
```

Sources:

- [Remote Subschemas & Executors](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/stitching/docs/getting-started/remote-subschemas)
- [Subscriptions in Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#resolving-a-subscription)